# Block visitors from autosurf

Tags: php, access-rules

I would like to know how can I block traffic from websites such as autosurf, traffic exchange etc. because I have a website where people gain credits from visiting and viewing their content on my website. The most of the traffic comes from social networks but Im afraid of getting traffic from websites I have mentioned above because I have adsense on web. Is there a way to disable access from such websites. Is it enough if I disable loading my website in iframe ? Is it is how can I do that.

Comment: And how may we help you with that?

Comment: If you want to check that your visitor is a human, rather than a bot, a CAPTCHA would do it. (Aside: would be interested in seeing your website, if it is live - are you paying people to watch adverts?).

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.wpwebhost.com/how-to-block-traffic-from-autosurf-sites-using-htaccess/ you can block AutoSurf with `.htaccess`. Copypasta:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} auto_surf_site\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} auto_surf\.com [NC,OR]
RewriteRule .* - [F]
```

I guess you could add a `RewriteRule` for every site you wanted to block.
Also note that blocking according to the referer probably doesn't catch 100% of visitors from that site.

Comment: Thank you for you answer but that is not going to help me because I would need to have a complete list of such websites and thats not possible. Is there some other way ?

Comment: @Stevik You could block any referred visitor. But that would also block sane visits such as from social networks. Creating a blacklist is likely your only option.

Comment: And what about the iframe thing I wrote in the question? Could that help me somehow. Because whene someone is using traffic exchange and he gets on my website my website is not on the top but the traffixexchange web site is ? Am I right ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution, most if not 100% of auto surfs block them selves using breaking out of frame codes (that will stop the auto-surf at certain website so destroy their business) so you can use a simple javascript that will break your site out of any frame, put this before

```
<script type="text/javascript">if (top.location != self.location)top.location = self.location</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it is possible to do so. You may try some autosurf or traffic exchange program so you have better understanding.

http://viewraise.com
http://hitleap.com

These 2 autosurf program both provide anonymous referer for http request header. So, block by .htaccess is not possible.